# What medical history questions are asked for a UK Class 1 Medical?

Tags: medical, caa-uk-regulations

For anyone who has been through a [Class 1 medical in the UK](https://www.caa.co.uk/aeromedical-examiners/medical-standards/), when they run through your medical history what sort of questions are they asking?

Answer (score 1):

In the general medical examination they will go through the medical history you have written in [FORM MED 160](https://www.caa.co.uk/Aeromedical-Examiners/Connecting-with-the-CAA/Medical-forms-available-for-download/).

Comment: Ok thanks. And where is the bar in terms of when to tick yes to a question on the medical history? i.e. do they want to know about every GP visit you've ever had, or only positive diagnoses?

Comment: @Bill The form clearly asks if you have ever had specific medical conditions, not about routine GP visits.

Comment: You need to fill in the form according to the instructions written in the last page. In doubt, you can ask or clarify on the day of the examination